# Where does Windows 2000 store whether the last shutdown was a restart or shutdown (switch off)?

Tags: shutdown, windows-2000

Where does Windows 2000 store whether the last shutdown was a **restart** or **shutdown** (switch off)?

[image: Windows 2000 Shutdown Dialog]

Is this in the registry or somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of registry searching I came across the key that stores this info:

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer
```

value `Shutdown Setting`

- 0x2 = Shut down
  Ends the session and shuts down Windows 2000 so that the power can be turned off safely.
- 0x4 = Restart
  Ends the session, shuts down Windows 2000, and starts Windows 2000 again.

This is documented fully on the [Microsoft TechNet - Explorer Shutdown](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc962586.aspx) page.